# understanding the meaning of わけはない

Tags: translation, particle-は, negation, formal-nouns

From [the Progressive Japanese-English dictionary](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E6%93%8D%E7%B8%A6):

> 彼を操縦するなど**わけはない**
>   I can easily twist [wind] him around [((英)) round] my little finger.

Can you please tell me what わけはない means in this sentence?
Thank you

Comment: I believe that clause is [訳が無い](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/237973/meaning/m0u/). 「訳」means reason. I feel like "there is no need to.." or "there is no reason to..." is a better translation.

Answer (score 4):

It uses the second definition at [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/wakeganai):

> 2. easy; simple

It is also the second definition at [dictonary.goo.ne.jp/jn](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/237973/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/):

> ２ 簡単である。手数がかからない。

In the sentence you provided, the particle が is changed to は.

Comment: I was worried by my answer. How can we know that the sentence isn't using defintion 1. in your link?

Comment: I think the difference is that する isn't directly attached to わけ. If was 彼を操縦するわけはない then it would definitely sound like "There is no way that I could manipulate him."

Comment: I'm more convinced by your answer but I'm interested to know if mine is valid, so I think I'll leave it there until the down votes roll in.

Comment: This should be another way to phrase the original sentence and preserve the "easy, simple" meaning: 彼を操縦するなどはわけがない。